# Django, mod_wsgi, apache2 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu-12.04, mod-wsgi

I know there are lot Of questions in SO on this issue. But none of them really helped me to solve this issue. 
I want to use Apache server with django in ubuntu 12.04. But I could not get it working:

sample is the project name

sample.wsgi:   path:  /var/www/sample/sample.wsgi

```
import os
import sys

path = '/var/www'
if path not in sys.path:
     sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'sample.settings'


import django.core.handlers.wsgi 
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

sample.com file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/sample.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sample.com
    ServerAlias www.sample.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sample

   <Directory /var/www/sample>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
   </Directory>

    WSGIProcessGroup sample.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess sample.com python-path=/var/www/sample:/var/www/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sample/sample.wsgi
```

I can run django server but it is not working with apache2 server.

EDIT:

Added line to /etc/hosts file

```
192.168.100.3   sample.com
```

It is giving me Internal error 500

output:  tail /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 105, in __new__
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]     app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]     self.check_apps_ready()
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3]     raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
[Wed Oct 26 07:58:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.100.3] AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Define not working. What exact errors? Where? BTW, you are missing a ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` directive to start with. You need to have one for ``WSGIProcessGroup`` to refer to. Go check the Django documentation on mod_wsgi again.

Comment: There are no errors, it is pointing to apache default page. I will try adding that. thank you

Comment: So your VirtualHost is being ignored because it isn't enabled, or you are trying to access site using an IP address instead of the hostname specified by ServerName and thus it is falling back to first VirtualHost, which is default site. What URL are you using in the browser?

Comment: `127.0.1.1` and `localhost` . I have added `WSGIDaemonProcess` line. same result.

Comment: I think you need to **enable** your **available** site: `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/sample.com /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. And don't forget to restart apache.

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sample.com: File exists`, it is already exists

Comment: You cannot use an IP address if you still have a default site. When using VirtualHost Apache relies on you using a proper hostname in the URL so it knows which virtual host to map it to. So either add your configuration to the default site VirtualHost, or add to your system host file 'sample.com' mapping to '127.0.0.1' and then use URL with 'sample.com' in it instead of IP address.

Comment: If you are just playing around doing development to learn Django, you are better off just using Django development server, or mod_wsgi-express and run it from command line. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi/4.5.7

Comment: Added sample.com to hosts file. It is giving me internal 500 error. Added error.log details to the question please check @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Which looks to be an issue with not having applications listed in ``INSTALLED_APPS``. Anyway, your mod_wsgi configuration is working at least, now it is a Django setup problem.

Comment: I will try and get it working. I have small doubts. In django documentation it is written that to edit `httpd.conf` file. I have created another file in sites-available, both work?  And I have wsgi.py already exists, I created another file sample.wsgi, can it be a problem?

Comment: `from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()` I added this line in sample.wsgi after removing last two lines. And got it working. thank you